# Pygame python how to draw a rect from variable

Tags: python, pygame

Im programming "snake" and just wondering how to draw a rect from variable.

```
head = pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(x, y, 60, 60))
```

How to draw it again, but only with variable "head"?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: `head` is the *rectangle representing the bounding area of changed pixels.* From [the docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's possible to do this to redraw the head:

```
head = pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(x, y, 60, 60))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, head)
```

I would personally just take the approach of first creating the rect and then drawing it as many times as you need to:

```
head = pygame.Rect(x, y, 60, 60)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, head)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, head)
```

Also, it's recommended to use [`screen.fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) instead:

```
head = pygame.Rect(x, y, 60, 60)
screen.fill(color, head)
```